# AngularJs, display function result in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to sum two columns in a function then display their result in the ui grid. any ideas about how to do this, then save the ui grid content in the database?

[see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX8Fi.png) 
so in my case : a and b are binded from the database, while I want angularjs to calculate their sum and add it in the column "Quantite reelle".
this is my grid code $scope.gridOptions = {

```
    showGridFooter: true,
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.core.on.renderingComplete($scope, function () {

            $timeout(function () {
                var gridBodyElem = document.getElementById(gridApi.grid.id + '-grid-container');
                gridApi.grid.element.on('mouseup', handleGridClick);
            });
        });
    }

};
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'Num', enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, enableCellEdit: false, width: '5%' },
    { name: 'CodeArticle', enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: 'Code Article ', width: '10%' },
    { name: 'Ref', enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: 'Référence ', width: '10%' },
    { name: 'Designation', enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: 'Désignation ', width: '30%' },
    { name: 'Stock', enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: "Qté théorique (a)", width: '13%' },
    { name: "ajust", enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: "Ajustement (b)", width: '12%' },
    { name: "sum", enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: "Quantité Réelle(a+b)", width: '14%' },
    { name: "motif", enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: "Motif", width: '20%' }
];
```

`
  thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set column field property to expression.

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: "sum", enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, field:'CalculateSum(a,b)',  displayName: "Quantité Réelle(a+b)", width: '14%' }
];

Here a & b are respective column names.

Comment: and how can the function CalculateSum(a,b) be?  Im beginner and trying to figure out how to work with ui-grid.

Comment: Define this in $scope.CalculateSum = function(a,b) {return a+b;}

Comment: apparently, the function is not getting the values of a and b from the grid. I guess they should be called diferently? like row.sum or idk?

Comment: You can also directly sum inside the field
.$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
{ name: "sum", enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, field:'a + b', displayName: "Quantité Réelle(a+b)", width: '14%' } ];

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the solutions have worked to me! the values of the columns arent getting read. everytime I use them, it shows undefined

Comment: let me try to execute this via giving data and will get back to you on this.

Comment: For calculated column field will not work in your example. It is in some different version on which I worked. I tested your scenario. You need to define cellTemplate  like mention below.                                                                                        cellTemplate: '<span>{{row.entity.column1 + " " + row.entity.column1}}</span>'. You can refer to this link also http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$scope.gridApi.grid.columns[column a].getAggregationValue() + 
$scope.gridApi.grid.columns[column b].getAggregationValue()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the solutions have worked to me! the values of the columns arent getting read. everytime I use them, it shows undefined –
whats the equivalent of $scope when It comes to a grid? so I can use the values of a specified column

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'Num', enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, enableCellEdit: false, width: '5%' },
    { name: 'CodeArticle', enableHiding: false,field:'CodeArticle', enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: 'Code Article ', width: '10%' },
    { name: 'Ref', enableHiding: false,enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: 'Référence ', width: '10%' },
    { name: 'Designation', enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: 'Désignation ', width: '30%' },
    { name: 'Stock', enableHiding: false,field:'Stock', enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: "Qté théorique (a)", width: '13%' },
    { name: "ajust", enableHiding: false, field: 'ajust', enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: "Ajustement (b)", width: '12%' },
    { name: "sum", enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, field: 'CalculateSum(ajust,Stock)', displayName: "Quantité Réelle(a+b)", width: '14%' },
    { name: "motif", enableHiding: false, enableColumnMenu: false, displayName: "Motif", width: '20%' }
];

$scope.CalculateSum = function (ajust, Stock) {


    return ajust + Stock;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [Tutorial: 323 More Binding examples](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20323%20More%20Binding%20examples) I created a [Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/evYBKjaxwMhLqRUt?preview), using a filter `calculateSum` to calculate the sum of both fields.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
  .filter('calculateSum', function () {
  return function (input, a, b) {
    return input[a]+input[b];
  };
});;

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$http', 'uiGridConstants'];

function MainCtrl($http, uiGridConstants) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      vm.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name'},
      { field: 'num1'},
      { field: 'num2'},
      { name: 'sum', field: uiGridConstants.ENTITY_BINDING, cellFilter: 'calculateSum:"num1":"num2"' }
    ]
  };

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      response.data.forEach(function(row){
        row.num1 = row.age;
        row.num2 = row.age*2;
      });
      vm.gridOptions.data = response.data;
    });
}
```